# created file sizes are different with matlab imwrite and cv2 imwrite

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I'm converting a matlab script to py file. Minimal Matlab code :

```
% PNG file is 32 bit. G is RGB and discardIMG is alpha channel
[G, map, discardIMG] = imread('file.png');
discardIMG = double(discardIMG);
discard = mod(floor(discardIMG / 2^(i - 1)), 2);
imwrite(uint8(255 * discard), 'file.png';
```

py equivalent which I type:

```
% imread with -1 reads all 4 channels. Without it only RGB is read.
G = cv2.imread('file.png', -1)
% alpha channel as discard image
discardIMG = G[:,:,3].astype(float)
discard = np.floor( (discardIMG / 2**(i - 1))% 2)   
cv2.imwrite('file2.png', (255*discard).astype(np.uint8))
```

The problem is matlab files are smaller in size than py files. For a number of 8 files;

`py saved file size  = [21,21,30,21,21,21,21,21]`

`mat saved file size = [17,17,24,17,17,17,17,17]`

I also checked final discard files and they do look same in content and size. Any ideas? What is this overhead with py files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the official documentation of cv2.imwrite from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite)
it's because of compression parameters. For png images default param is 3.  A higher value means a smaller size and longer compression time and vice versa. So you can provide another parameter like below, it can be any value between 0 to 9 for png images.

```
cv2.imwrite('file2.png', (255*discard).astype(np.uint8), [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9])
```